# Why are these 2 regressors collinear

Tags: r, regression, correlation, estimation

```
x1 <- rep(1:20, 5)
x2 <- rep(c(13, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 19, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 9, 13, 9, 13, 19), 5)
e <- rnorm(100)
y <- x1 + x2 + e
summary(lm(y ~ as.factor(x1) + x2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(x1) + x2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.66003 -0.71365 -0.05933  0.69159  1.72852 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      13.3754     0.4630  28.891  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)2   -3.2496     0.6547  -4.963 3.84e-06 ***
as.factor(x1)3   -1.8634     0.6547  -2.846  0.00562 ** 
as.factor(x1)4   -0.2589     0.6547  -0.395  0.69360    
as.factor(x1)5    0.9180     0.6547   1.402  0.16475    
as.factor(x1)6    5.4959     0.6547   8.394 1.36e-12 ***
as.factor(x1)7    6.7137     0.6547  10.254 3.09e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)8    6.8919     0.6547  10.527  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)9   15.2879     0.6547  23.350  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)10   5.9102     0.6547   9.027 7.77e-14 ***
as.factor(x1)11   6.6589     0.6547  10.171 4.50e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)12   7.8456     0.6547  11.983  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)13   8.6241     0.6547  13.172  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)14   9.9339     0.6547  15.173  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)15  14.9257     0.6547  22.797  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)16  11.3139     0.6547  17.281  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)17  16.3219     0.6547  24.930  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)18  13.4459     0.6547  20.537  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)19  18.6040     0.6547  28.415  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)20  25.6696     0.6547  39.207  < 2e-16 ***
x2                    NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.035 on 80 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.984, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9802 
F-statistic: 259.6 on 19 and 80 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The reason that I repeat the vectors 5 times is that it represents 5 weeks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the output from the summary?  It will help answer your question.  What is telling you they are collinear?

Comment: the output contains that "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have two regressors, you have 20 regressors + 1 intercept. This is because you used `as.factor`, which converts one vector into one 0-1 vector per distinct value, minus one vector to avoid the linear combination of these columns that would equal the intercept column.

You can then easily see that there is a linear combination of the first 20 columns that equals the last one, which is then dropped when fitting:

```
x <- model.matrix(lm(y ~ as.factor(x1) + x2))
comb <- x[,1] * x2[1] + x[,2:20] %*% (x2[2:20] - x2[1])

print(cbind(comb, x2))
```

The reason there is collinearity is because the pattern of `x2` repeats every 20 points, so you span a big enough space with those 20 factors to include it.

Comment: Yes I realized this last night. Thank you. For anyone who comes across this issue in the future another way of putting it is you cant use dummy variables that are less "fine" (not sure the appropriate word) than your most "fine" dummy. In this case I was using a dummy for 20 different products (beers) and then a dummy for a characteristic (type of beer) however there was no variation in the characteristic and thus the characteristic was collinear with the dummy for products.